# How to efficiently update a dynamically drawn background on hundreds of elements

Tags: javascript, canvas

So, I have table that has a dynamically drawn background on its cells, which gets updated fairly regularly. This table can have hundreds of rows so efficiency is quite important.

My current solution involves drawing the background onto a canvas, then using this drawing as the background image on the cells via a data URI.

```
cell.css({backgroundImage:'url(' + canvas.toDataURL('image/png')+ ')' });
```

This works ok, but the html source gets rather large with all the duplication from the encoded image, and ultimately makes some browsers struggle.

**Is there a way to somehow reuse the same data URI without duplicating it?**

Other ideas I've considered:
- directly use the canvas element as a background with `-webkit-canvas` or `-moz-element`, but this does not seem very compatible with internet explorer.
- absolutely position a canvas in each cell and redraw the contents, but this doesn't feel very efficient when we get to hundreds of rows.

Comment: How often does your image update?

Comment: The images update due to user interaction, so it could be multiple times a second or not at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Look into using [Canvas2Blob](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob).

Basically you can get a URL string by calling `URL.createObjectURL(blob);` where `blob` is the object returned from the polyfill `canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {...});`

The advantage of this is that a `Blob` is 3/4 the size of a dataURI string because of the encoding, and should not be as memory / processor intensive when using it 100s of times.

**Option 2:**

If you really want to use `canvas.toDataURL('image/png');` then store it to a string variable like

```
var str = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
// ...
cell.css({backgroundImage:'url(' + str + ')' });
```

Depending on the browser implementation, calling `.toDataURL()` can be a very expensive function call, and since all of the cells need the same background, you'd be better off just storing it to a string.

Comment: I actually do use option 2 in my code, my issue with it is basically the bloated html source that slows down the browser when there are lots of rows. Instead of outputting the whole string I really wanted to just reference one encoded copy of the image.

Option 1 looks interesting, I'll have a play with it.

Comment: @Coin_op Option 1 is a lot better because an object URL is about the same length as a normal URL, like approximately 20 characters or so. That's certainly a ton better than a dataURI

Comment: It does seem better from a size of HTML perspective, but it doesn't render as fast, I get a slight flicker when the new URL is loading, I'm not sure if that will be acceptable yet.

Comment: @Coin_op yes, the flickering will be worse with an object URL since the dataURI will load instantly, given the fact that the string itself contains the image data.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to somehow reuse the same data URI without duplicating it?

No, a Data-URI is just a textual representation of binary data, here a generated PNG (or JPEG) file. If you need to change content the binary data must be changed first, then the data-URI encoded based on that. Therefor it cannot be reused.

`toDataURL()` is also a very slow process, and using this technique also involves building, encoding, compressing, parsing, decompressing and decoding the bitmap data each and every time, this on top of encoding/decoding the file to and from Base-64 representation.

> How to efficiently update a dynamically drawn background on hundreds of elements

**Here is what I would do:**

- Use a single canvas element placed behind the table itself and at the same size (use CSS for placement, but measure the pixel width/height for canvas size).
- Make a single function which iterates the table cells to find out their pixel sizes, use this once initially and every time the browser is resized.
- Render the rectangles directly to the canvas element

## Example

```js
var table = document.querySelector("table"),
    canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

getArray();  // and on resize if needed

function getArray() {
  // todo: iterate table here to find sizes for each cell.
  // For simplicity just the table width and height is measured in this example:
  var rect = table.getBoundingClientRect();
  canvas.width = rect.width;
  canvas.height = rect.height;
}

// render for demo -
(function loop() {
  render();
  requestAnimationFrame(loop)
})();

function render() {
  var cw = canvas.width * 0.5,
      ch = canvas.height * 0.5;
  for(var y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
    for(var x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
      ctx.fillStyle = "hsl(" + (360*Math.random()) + ",80%,70%)";
      ctx.fillRect(x * cw, y * ch, cw, ch);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
div {position:relative}
canvas, table {position:absolute; left:0; top:0}
table {border:1px solid #000}
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas></canvas>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

## Image caching

Another method is to pre-generate an array with images and setting their source to the data-uri.

Then use the image directly as background for the table.

Comment: I realise the data URI needs to be regenerated every time the image changes, but I was wondering if it was possible to use this data more than once without outputting it directly into the source. I just want to reference this dynamic image rather than reprint it.

I thought about doing it your way, but it seems like a lot of work resizing and redrawing all the images when they are the same. Its repetition I could do without.

Comment: @Coin_op you can always generate an array with image elements which src comes from the data-uri, then set the image itself as background

Comment: Upvote for using html5 canvas as a speedy backing store. And to reassure @Coin_op, canvas is very efficient at fast updates/refreshes and is fully supported by IE>8 (pre-IE9 has only a few percentage points browser share and much of that small share is in China).